# Two Binomial Distributions with conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

I'm stumbling on what I think is just a simple problem but am a bit out of practice (out of school for 30 years and attempting to relearn some old stat information):

Two independent binomial distributions as follows:
A: Binomial N = 10, p=70%
B: Binomial N = 10, p=20%

What is the probability of B >= A given than B is equal to 5? I've started by attempting to solve for the probability of B >= A and B = 5 over probability that B = 5. Denominator is straight forward but I am struggling to take the appropriate next steps on the numerator. My text only has the question and numeric solution and I'm unable to match the answer. Since B is given to equal 5, isn't my numerator simply the probability that A is <= 5? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: If B is 5, then you are just computing the probability that $A \leq  5$. You can also check that it's consistent with the more general formula $P(B=5, A\leq 5) / P(B=5) = P(B=5) P(A \leq5) / P(B=5) = P(A \leq 5)$. Independence is used in the first equality.

Comment: That was my thought, I'll check my calculations again as I must have made a computational error (but I've checked over it a few times already). Thank your for your response and confirmation.